# iOS Coordinate System is Wrong

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios8

I seem to be experiencing problems with the iOS8 coordinate system.  I am trying to figure out if this is the way it is supposed to be or a bug. Seems like a bug to me.  But when I access the frame property of an element I get different coordinates if I run it as iOS8 vs iOS 7.  It seems like the iOS8 doubles the numbers or is not taking  into account that I am running it on a retina screen.  Also it seems to only affect the frames that don't have specific constraints on them. if I add a width constraint then width is correct but if it is auto calculated width then it is double.

I created a test project here https://github.com/smitt04/TestCoodinates for anyone to try.

Also pasted here with out storyboard.

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var version: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        label.text = "Frame is \(button.frame)"
        version.text = "iOS: \(UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion)"
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

and the outcome is

**iOS 7**

[image: iOS7]

**iOS 8**

[image: iOS 8]

Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is too soon. The view's size is not yet set properly.

Comment: That seemed to fix it even though i now get `0.5` pixel difference between the iOS versions. But, I thought `viewDidLoad` was so that you can initialize your view before it appears and the fact it only gets called once. And it is a little strange to me that this works fine in older ios versions but not anymore in `iOS 8`

Comment: I think they switch the coordinate system. I've been setting some frames in viewDidLayoutSubviews and when I use [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds as reference coordinate system seems to be inverted

Comment: Re: the 0.5 px difference: are the actual hardware (or simulators) you're using different in terms of retina versus non-retina display? I'd imagine that there could be rounding errors in that case.

Comment: the same happen to me issue in viewDidLoad, i set frames in view didAppear solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is never reliable to get frame coordinates from `viewDidLoad`. It just seemed more reliable in iOS7 vs iOS8.  The best place that I found to set or change coordinates is in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews` depending on what you wanted.